# Need to temporarily disable access to ASP.Net MVC 3 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the easiest way to temporarily disable access to ASP.Net MVC 3 website?
Access is restricted to specific IP or localhost
All external users get the text: "Matrix reloaded ..." or "Under Construction".

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so, just right click on the website folder, then mess around with the authentication settings in the security section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an app_offline.htm email to the root folder and the site will be unaccessible and any url's requested will show the app_offline.htm contents.

**Edit**: didn't notice the ability to be able to access locally. One way to take the site down from external users would be to add a http module to the site.  The easiest (hacky) way is put the module straight in the app_code folder. something like:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
 public class BlockRemoteModule : IHttpModule 
 {
  public BlockRemoteModule() {}

  public void Dispose() {}

  public void Init(HttpApplication application) 
  {
   application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
  }

  public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"] != HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"])
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 503;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Under Construction.");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

And then register it in the web.config (assuming iis7+)

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="BlockRemoteModule" type="YourNameSpace.BlockRemoteModule,App_code" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I think he wants to still be able to access the website from localhost or internal networks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with action filter, that way you can choose which actions/controllers won't be accessible. This action filter could just check for certain appSetting value and if it's set to true/false it would redirect to under maintenance view.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure redirection in your application server (IIS in this case):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx